# Throwing: 'Could not load file or assembly error' when I run my application release .exe

Tags: c#, exception, json.net, .net-assembly, release

I am getting the following error written to the applications error log file when I run the .exe of the program in the release folder:

```
<logEntry>
  <Date>23/06/2015 20:00:50</Date>
  <Exception>
    <Source>Twitter_twitinvi</Source>
    <Message>Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</Message>
    <Stack>   at Twitter_twitinvi.Program.RunTwitterApplication()
at Twitter_twitinvi.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\nikhil\Desktop\MediaLabs\Backup\BackupTwitter\Program.cs:line 64</Stack>
  </Exception>
</logEntry>
```

I have tried reinstalling Newtonsoft to make sure there is no conflict with versioning. The application runs fine through VS2012

My intention is to restart the application when I catch an exception, here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            RunTwitterApplication();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogWriter.LogWriter.WriteLog(e);
            Process.Start(@"C:\Users\nikhil\Desktop\MediaLabs\Backup\Twitter_twitinvi\Twitter_twitinvi\obj\Release\Twitter_twitinvi.exe");

        }
    }

    private static void RunTwitterApplication()
```

Will this work? Once the .exe file starts running without the above mentioned error ofcourse

Thank you

Comment: I've answered the first half of your question below. The second part about your try/catch block really ought to be its own question.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you're not copying a resource properly.

Go into Visual Studio's Solution Explorer window, open the "References" tab for your project, then make sure the "Copy Local" property for the `Newtonsoft.Json` reference is set to "True".

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I have checked the Copy local property and it is set to true. Is there anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: Did you have to change the property, or was it always set to "True"? If you had to change it, try cleaning before rebuilding.

Also make sure there isn't a little yellow exclamation mark (!) next to your "References" entry for `Newtonsoft.Json`. The ! means that the reference is invalid, and you need to set it again. In fact, it may be a good idea to just re-set the reference regardless. (Delete the reference, then re-add it).